# Import XML google spreadsheet is not working Properly

Tags: xpath, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

find attached link for my Google spreadsheet in which i tried to pull out the data from booking.com.

i retrieved Hotel name in column. it successfully retrieved the hotel name. but not work with every column. Output is like this.

even i referenced the formula correctly. but it automatically changed to like this..=CONTINUE(E1, 2, 1)

red highlighted cell is having problem. look there.

Please find below link for your reference. Thanks in Advance.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AtjX3Ttg50IydHJzR1FMSkJyY0U1bHBSeWtrMDRSZ1E

Answer (score 0):

The formula in E1:

`=ImportXML(D1,"//div[@id = 'wrap-hotelpage-top']/h1[@class='item']/span")`

is returning a 2 x 2 array. To return just the top left-cell and avoid population of the CONTINUE functions (so that you can fill down successfully), use

`=INDEX(ImportXML(D1,"//div[@id = 'wrap-hotelpage-top']/h1[@class='item']/span");1;1)`

Comment: Hi AdML, thanks for your reply first.. I used this....and it  successfully retrived without any worry `=ImportXML(D1;"//div[@id = 'wrap-hotelpage-top']//h1[@class='item']")`. tell me how can i suppress `continous function` . its annoying..

Comment: after spending so much time on pc. i get that code works. i too consider and learn from your code also. thanks

Comment: this code works very well without `index` `=ImportXML(D1;"//div[@id = 'wrap-hotelpage-top']//h1[@class='item']")'. how this works without `index`.